# How do I rig this cointainer?

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

I have made this container for a project, and I have to make it so it can be opened.

It has two springs outside and should follow the lid, but the lid's pivot point is a little offset for the spring, as you can see in the image. I added a bone for the container, another for the lid, and I suppose another one for the spring.

Could anyone help? I don't know how to rig it properly.

Comment: May be this video can help you:D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Xgw-mutOv4

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured out by looking another post. I needed another bone that goes to the tail of the spring bone, and a Constrain 'Strech to'.

[image]

[image]